# Append Columns C and D to A and B in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which is 12 columns by 12 rows. I want to append columns C and D, E and F, G and H and I and J to columns A & B making it 2x72. when I try to do it with:

```
df = dffvstats.iloc[:,[0,1]]
df2 = dffvstats.iloc[:,[2,3]]
df.append(df2)
```

it gives me:

```
             0            1              2      3
0        Index  DJIA S&P500            NaN    NaN
1   Market Cap     2521.74B            NaN    NaN
2       Income       86.80B            NaN    NaN
3        Sales      347.15B            NaN    NaN
4      Book/sh         3.87            NaN    NaN
5      Cash/sh         3.76            NaN    NaN
6     Dividend         0.88            NaN    NaN
7   Dividend %        0.57%            NaN    NaN
8    Employees       147000            NaN    NaN
9   Optionable          Yes            NaN    NaN
10   Shortable          Yes            NaN    NaN
11       Recom         1.90            NaN    NaN
0          NaN          NaN            P/E  30.09
1          NaN          NaN    Forward P/E  27.12
2          NaN          NaN            PEG   1.53
3          NaN          NaN            P/S   7.26
4          NaN          NaN            P/B  39.70
5          NaN          NaN            P/C  40.87
6          NaN          NaN          P/FCF  31.35
7          NaN          NaN    Quick Ratio   1.00
8          NaN          NaN  Current Ratio   1.10
9          NaN          NaN        Debt/Eq   1.89
10         NaN          NaN     LT Debt/Eq   1.65
11         NaN          NaN          SMA20  3.47%
```

anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df.head(5)` and `df2.head(5)` please?

Comment: <bound method NDFrame.head of              0            1
0        Index  DJIA S&P500
1   Market Cap     2521.74B
2       Income       86.80B
3        Sales      347.15B
4      Book/sh         3.87
5      Cash/sh         3.76
6     Dividend         0.88
7   Dividend %        0.57%
8    Employees       147000
9   Optionable          Yes
10   Shortable          Yes
11       Recom         1.90>

Comment: <bound method NDFrame.head of                 2      3
0             P/E  30.09
1     Forward P/E  27.12
2             PEG   1.53
3             P/S   7.26
4             P/B  39.70
5             P/C  40.87
6           P/FCF  31.35
7     Quick Ratio   1.00
8   Current Ratio   1.10
9         Debt/Eq   1.89
10     LT Debt/Eq   1.65
11          SMA20  3.47%>

Comment: You forgot the `(5)`

Comment: @Zwink I see you have feedback. Have you tested [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69063579/16343464)?

Comment: i wasnt able to. the column indexes are numerical. i tried renamingto abcdefghijk and l but i got a numpy error.

Comment: renaming the columns turns the datatype from Dataframe to ndarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `dffvstats` dataframe looks like:

```
>>> dffvstats
             0            1              2      3   # 4 5 6 7 and so on
0        Index  DJIA S&P500            P/E  30.09
1   Market Cap     2521.74B    Forward P/E  27.12
2       Income       86.80B            PEG   1.53
3        Sales      347.15B            P/S   7.26
4      Book/sh         3.87            P/B  39.70
5      Cash/sh         3.76            P/C  40.87
6     Dividend         0.88          P/FCF  31.35
7   Dividend %        0.57%    Quick Ratio   1.00
8    Employees       147000  Current Ratio   1.10
9   Optionable          Yes        Debt/Eq   1.89
10   Shortable          Yes     LT Debt/Eq   1.65
11       Recom         1.90          SMA20  3.47%
```

And you want that:

```
>>> out
                0            1
0           Index  DJIA S&P500
1      Market Cap     2521.74B
2          Income       86.80B
3           Sales      347.15B
4         Book/sh         3.87
5         Cash/sh         3.76
6        Dividend         0.88
7      Dividend %        0.57%
8       Employees       147000
9      Optionable          Yes
10      Shortable          Yes
11          Recom         1.90
12            P/E        30.09
13    Forward P/E        27.12
14            PEG         1.53
15            P/S         7.26
16            P/B        39.70
17            P/C        40.87
18          P/FCF        31.35
19    Quick Ratio         1.00
20  Current Ratio         1.10
21        Debt/Eq         1.89
22     LT Debt/Eq         1.65
23          SMA20        3.47%
```

Try:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([dffvstats.loc[:, cols].values
                       for cols in zip(dffvstats.columns[::2], 
                                       dffvstats.columns[1::2])]))
```

Explanation:

1. Start to get column pairwise with zip

```
>>> list(dffvstats.columns[::2])  # even columns
[0, 2]

>>> (dffvstats.columns[1::2])  # odd columns
[1, 3]

>>> list(zip(dffvstats.columns[::2], dffvstats.columns[1::2]))
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
```

2. Split dataframe into sub dataframe:

```
tmp = [dffvstats.loc[:, cols].values
           for cols in zip(dffvstats.columns[::2], dffvstats.columns[1::2])]

>>> tmp[0]
array([['Index', 'DJIA S&P500'],
       ['Market Cap', '2521.74B'],
       ['Income', '86.80B'],
       ['Sales', '347.15B'],
       ['Book/sh', '3.87'],
       ['Cash/sh', '3.76'],
       ['Dividend', '0.88'],
       ['Dividend %', '0.57%'],
       ['Employees', '147000'],
       ['Optionable', 'Yes'],
       ['Shortable', 'Yes'],
       ['Recom', '1.90']], dtype=object)

>>> tmp[1]
array([['P/E', '30.09'],
       ['Forward P/E', '27.12'],
       ['PEG', '1.53'],
       ['P/S', '7.26'],
       ['P/B', '39.70'],
       ['P/C', '40.87'],
       ['P/FCF', '31.35'],
       ['Quick Ratio', '1.00'],
       ['Current Ratio', '1.10'],
       ['Debt/Eq', '1.89'],
       ['LT Debt/Eq', '1.65'],
       ['SMA20', '3.47%']], dtype=object)
```

3. Concatenate all small dataframes into a big one with `np.concatenate` instead of `pd.concat` because you have a list of ndarray.

Comment: Thanks this is it! could you explain to me how it works?

Comment: @Zwink. I updated my answer with some explanation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with pd.concat:

```
pd.concat([df[['A', 'B']], df[['C', 'D']].rename(columns={'C':'A', 'D':'B'}), df[['E', 'F']].rename(columns={'E':'A', 'F':'B'}), df[['G', 'H']].rename(columns={'G':'A', 'H':'B'}), df[['I', 'J']].rename(columns={'I':'A', 'G':'B'})])
```

Comment: the indexes are numerical. and i cant seem to get them to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient to reshape, use `numpy`:

```
a = dffvstats.values
pd.DataFrame(np.c_[a[:, ::2].flatten('F'),
                   a[:, 1::2].flatten('F')],
             columns=['A', 'B'])
```

It concatenates all the even columns together, same with odd, and assembles both in a two columns array to form a dataframe.